# How to make Ruby regex expression with some conditional inputs

Tags: regex, ruby

This is my inputs looks like

format 1: `2022-09-23 18:40:45.846 I/getUsers: fetching data`

format 2: `11:54:54.619 INFO loadingUsers:23 - visualising: "Entered to dashboard`

This is the expression which is working for format one, i want to have the same (making changes to this) to handle both formats

```
^([0-9-]+ [:0-9.]+)\s(?<level>\w+)[\/+](?<log>.*)
```

it results as for format 1:

> level I

> message   getUsers: fetching data

for 2nd it should be as

> level INFO

> message   loadingUsers:23 - visualising: "Entered to dashboard

Help would be appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^([0-9-]+ [:0-9.]+|[0-9:.]+)\s(?<level>\w+)[\/+\s]+(?<log>.*)
```

See the [Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/ZhyCffcaDIu71P).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `([0-9-]+ [:0-9.]+|[0-9:.]+)` - Group 1: one or more digits/hyphens, space, one or more digits/colons/dots, or one or more digits/colons/dots
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `(?<level>\w+)` - Group "level": one or more letters, digits or underscores
- `[\/+\s]+` -  one or more slashes, `+` or whitespaces
- `(?<log>.*)` - Group "log": zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

If you want to precise your Group 1 pattern (although I consider using a loose pattern fine in these scenarios), you can replace `([0-9-]+ [:0-9.]+|[0-9:.]+)` with `(\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\.\d+|\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\.\d+)`, see [this regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/NBaZRzInNMY0zc).